# A Question on the Use of Aubin-Lions Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am now studying a paper about the construction of weak solutions, and I am not able to fully understand how the paper argues the convergence using the Aubin-Lions lemma:

For any $T > 0$, we have a sequence of approximate solutions $u_\epsilon \in L^2([0,T], H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $\partial_tu_\epsilon \in L^2([0,T], W^{-1,\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n))$. The paper argues that one can extract a subsequence (here WLOG we assume the original sequence does the job) such that $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^2([0,T],L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

To apply the Aubin-Lions lemma, we have to identify a chain of 3 spaces $X_0, X, X_1$ such that $X_0 \subset X$ compactly and $X \subset X_1$ continuously. Here I have identified those spaces as: $X_0 = H^1, X = L^2_{loc}, X_1 = W^{-1,\frac{n}{n-1}}$. It is clear that this holds true when $n=2$, and in the general case when $n \ge 2$, the compact embedding part follows from the Sobolev compact embedding theorem. Maybe I missed something pretty trivial, but it is not quite clear to me why $L^2_{loc}$ embeds in $W^{-1,\frac{n}{n-1}}$ continuously. Could someone give me a hint how to make sense of this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the Aubin-Lion lemma:

> **Theorem (Aubin-Lion).** Let $X_0$, $X$, and $X_1$ be three Banach spaces with $X_0\subset X\subset X_1$. Suppose that $X_0$ is compactly embedded in $X$ and that $X$ is continuously embedded in $X_1$. Suppose that $1<p,q<\infty$ and
> $$ W =\{ u \in L^p ([0,T];X_0) : \partial_t u \in L^q ([0,T];X_1) \}. $$
> Then $W$ is compactly embedded into $L^p (0,T;X)$.

To apply this theorem into your setting, note that the sequence $\{u_\varepsilon\}$ consists of elements in
$$ W =\{ u \in L^2([0,T];H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)) : \partial_t u_\varepsilon \in L^2([0,T];W^{-1,n/(n-1)}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \}.$$

Hence for any open ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is easy to see that $\{u_\varepsilon\}$ also belong to
$$ W(B) =\{ u \in L^2([0,T];H^1(B)) : \partial_t u_\varepsilon \in L^2([0,T];W^{-1,n/(n-1)}(B)) \}.$$
By Rellich-Kondrachov's theorem, $H^1(B)$ is compactly embedded into $L^2(B)$. Also, by Holder's inequality and Sobolev embedding theorem, one can see that $L^2(B)$ is continuously embedded into $W^{-1,n/(n-1)}(B)$. Hence we can apply the Aubin-Lion lemma that there exists a subsequence $\{u_\varepsilon \}$ (still denote it by same notation) such that $u_{\varepsilon}\rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(0,T;L^2(B))$. Since $B$ was arbitrary chosen, one can show that there exists a subsequence of $\{u_\varepsilon\}$ that converges $L^2(0,T;L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

One may find this argument in establishing weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equation in whole space. If you need a further elaboration, let me know.

Comment: Aha, so instead of applying the theorem to the whole space we first pass it to any compact subset. And then we can obtain the convergence in $L^2_{loc}$. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, I would like to ask why $L^2(B) \subset W^{-1,n/(n-1)}(B)$ continuously? In my understanding, this is equivalent to saying that $W^{1,n}_0(B)$ continuously embeds in $L^2(B)$. But classical sobolev embedding only tells us that $W^{1,n}_0(B)$ is embedded in $L^p(B)$ for $p \ge n$. Isn't it that this will be an issue if the spatial dimension $n > 2$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nagi Observe that $B$ has a finite measure. So $W^{1,n}_0(B)$ is continuously embedded into $L^2(B)$.

Comment: Ah I forgot about this fact. I was still thinking about the whole domain case. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy the big ocean of the PDE!

Comment: Will, would you care to elaborate as to why there is a subsequence that converges in $L^2(0, T ; L_{loc}^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Comment: sorry, I forgot tag you, @WillKwon

Comment: @reverendjamesm Hi, you need to think about the definition of $L^p_loc $ convergence. By definition, fix a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a ball $B$ containing $K$. Since we can subtract subsequences of sequences by Aubin-Lions lemma on $B$, then the convergence still hold on $K$.

Comment: I see, thank you. What do you mean the convergence still holds on $K$? You'll only have a subsequence converging on $K$, right? What I trying to say is the following: the subsequences you can extract by Aubin-Lions lemma on $B$ might depend on this $B$. Do you need to take $B$ to be balls of increasing radius and then use a diagonalisation argument to have a subsequence that converges in $L^2_{loc}$?

Comment: @reverendjamesm Ahh... you are right, sorry for confusion. I forgot the notion of convergence on $L_{loc}$. Using that construction, we can obtain desired convergence in $L_{loc}$.